# Python code not looping back to the top

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

For my programming class we have to make a simple text adventure style code with randomization. I can get the basics done, but when I try to add a retry to the end, it only asks the user if they want to retry over and over instead of going back up to the beginning of the code.

```
import random

def main():

    cave1=('text1')

    cave2=('text2')

    #Radom assignment for caves
    checkCave=random.randint(1,2)

    #Text of situation
    displayIntro='Two caves, one good, one bad'
    print(displayIntro)

    #input for cave choice.  
    chooseCave=int(input('Which cave do you enter?: (enter a 1 or 2): '))

    while chooseCave<1 or chooseCave>2:
        print('Error: please enter a 1 or a 2.')
    print()

    #outcome
    print('You slowly walk towards the cave.')
    print()

    if checkCave==1:
        print(cave1)
    else:
        print(cave2)
    print()

    again='y'
    while True:
        while True:
            again=input('Do you want to try again? y for yes, n to quit: ')
            if again in ('y','n'):
                break
            print('Invalid input.')
        if again=='y':
            continue
        else:
            print('Goodbye')
            break

    return again

main()
```

any help would be appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: continue is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

`continue` only means to start the next iteration of the `for` loop or `while` loop it is found inside of. You'll need an outer for loop if you want to loop the outer code.

Putting things into functions might help to make things easier on you.

Good luck!